# Redhat data virtualization quickstarts missing in version 6.3

Tags: redhat-datavirt

I am trying to follow the JBoss Data Virtualization quickstarts at:
[Quick Starts Guide Red Hat JBoss Data Virtualization 6.3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_data_virtualization/6.3/html-single/quick_starts_guide/)

I downloaded the quickstart kit from:

[dv_quickstart-2.1.0-dist.zip](https://developers.redhat.com/download-manager/file/dv_quickstart-2.1.0-dist.zip)

However, the quickstarts directory  EAP_HOME/quickstarts referenced in the document is missing.  Any idea on where I can find the quickstarts referenced in the document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case others have the same problem, the quickstarts are available as part of the 6.3.1 installer download in the customer portal at:

[Red Hat JBoss Data Virtualization 6.3.0 Installer](https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/softwareDownload.html?softwareId=45751)